# Is there any real reason to set neural net batch sizes to powers of 2?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

...besides making people think that maybe you took some computer science courses?  I see it frequently in vignettes online.  Batch sizes are 256, or 64, or whatever.

If I were to do rigorous testing on `for batchsize in range(258)`, would I have any reason to expect measurable discontinuous jumps at `2**n+1`?

My intuition is that modern software is so far abstracted from the guts of the computer that such tricks matter as much as the impacts of these keystrokes on local earthquake probability.

But maybe I'm wrong?  Hence the question.

Comment: Some people say this is faster, e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20179/what-is-the-advantage-of-keeping-batch-size-a-power-of-2 However a brief google search implies that this is not necessarily consistent. Either way, you're definitely not the first one to ask this, so maybe you will find some more info by searching (wish I could say more, but I don't know anything about this myself...).